# Ho to justify this inequality involving real positive numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $N\ge 2$, $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$, $a\ge 0, b>0$. Why the inequality
$$\left(1+\frac{a}{b}\right)^{-1/(N-1)}\ge 1-\frac{a}{(N-1)b}$$
holds true?

During the math class today, the professor used it without justifying that.

Could someone please tell where comes from?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality is related, but that is for non-negative exponents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed real number $r < 0$ is the function
$$
 f: (-1, \infty) \to \Bbb R, f(x) = (1+x)^r
$$
a *convex* function (the second derivative is strictly positive). It follows that
$$
 f(x) \ge f(0) + f'(0) \cdot x = 1+rx
$$
for all $ x > -1$.

Setting $x =a/b$ and $r=-1/(N-1)$ gives the desired estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x = a/b$ and $n = N-1$ to simplify notations. Your inequality is equivalent to

$$
{1\over 1+x} \geq \Bigl(1-{x\over n}\Bigr)^n.
$$
We have in fact$$
{1\over 1+x} \geq e^{-x} \geq \Bigl(1-{x\over n}\Bigr)^n.
$$
The last inequality is classical and holds as soon as $x \geq 0$ and $(1-x/n) \geq 0$, which holds in our particular case.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove your inequality using AM-GM.

Let's set $t= \frac ab \geq 0$, $m=N-1 \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, your inequality can be transformed as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{1+t}} & \ge & 1-\frac tm \\
& \Leftrightarrow & \\
\frac{t\sqrt[m]{1+t} + m}m& \ge & \sqrt[m]{1+t} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, note that for $ t \geq 0$ you have $\sqrt[m]{1+t}\geq 1$, so you have

$$\frac{t\sqrt[m]{1+t} + m}m \geq \frac{t + m}m=\frac{(t+1) + m-1}m \stackrel{AM-GM}{\geq}\sqrt[m]{(1+t)\cdot 1^{m-1}}$$

Done.

Comment: trancelocation, thank you. But what does mean AM-GM?

Comment: @User1010 : This is the inequality between the arithmetic and the geometric means. You might want to checkout this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities